# How to customize hydra run dir and sweep subdir based on values of a sweep?

Tags: fb-hydra

I am using hydra to organize my configurations and output folders for a project. This project involves first specifying a particular objective that can differ in a few parameters. Then that objective can be optimized by different kinds of optimization procedures, where each optimization has its own specific hyperparameters.

So far, it has been straightforward to use hydra's multisweep functionality to explore different objectives, for a single kind of optimization. I have been using string interpolation in my main config.yaml file. Suppose `objective` and `experiment` are config groups, and `optimization` is a config group under `experiment`.

```
filepaths: 
  # filenames
  objective_data: objective_data.csv # contains intermediate output useful for all experiments
  experiment_data: experiment_output.csv # contains final output specific only to a single experiment configuration
  # important subdirectories to keep distinct
  objective_subdir: param1=${objective.feature1.param1}/param2=${objective.feature1.param2}
  experiment_subdir: optimization=${experiment.optimization.name}/num_trials=${experiment.num_trials}/learning_rate=${experiment.optimization.learning_rate}/seed=${seed}
  leaf_subdir: ${filepaths.objective_subdir}/${filepaths.experiment_subdir}

hydra:
  run:
    dir: outputs/${filepaths.leaf_subdir}
  job:
    chdir: True
    config:
      override_dirname:
        exclude_keys:
          - filepaths.leaf_subdir
          - objective.feature1.param1
          - objective.feature1.param2
          - experiment.optimization.name
          - experiment.num_trials
          - experiment.optimization.learning_rate
          - seed
  sweep:
    dir: multirun
    subdir: ${filepaths.leaf_subdir}
```

And my conf directory structure is the following:

```
conf
├── config.yaml
├── objective
│   ├── basic.yaml
│   └── feature1
│       └── params.yaml
└── experiment
    ├── basic.yaml
    └── optimization
        ├── reinforcement_learning.yaml
        └── replicator_dynamic.yaml
```

When I use multisweep, I can get the following directory structure:

```
multirun
├── multirun.yaml
└── param1=10
    └── param2=10
        ├── objective_data.csv
        ├── optimization=reinforcement_learning
        │   └── num_trials=100
        │        └── learning_rate=1e-4
        │            └── rd_hparam=5
        │               └── seed=42
        │                   └── output.csv
        │ 
        └── optimization=replicator_dynamic
            └── num_trials=1
                 └── learning_rate=1e-4
                     └── rd_hparam=5
                        └── seed=42
                            └── output.csv
```

But really, I don't want to have to branch with `rd_hparam` in the reinforcement_learning optimization, or to have to branch with `learning_rate` subfolder in the replicator_dynamic optimization, because those values have nothing to do with those configurations. This is because  `learning_rate` is a hyperparameter specific to `reinforcement_learning` and `rd_param` is a parameter specific to `reinforcement_learning`.

However, it would be useful to keep other keys excluded from the `override_dirname`, like `seed`,  (like is described [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/configure_hydra/workdir/#configuration-for-run)) so that they could be the later parents of my job-specific `output.csv` files

But I really want to use multisweep to run the different optimization jobs all at once. Ideally, I want something like the following directory structure:

```
multirun
├── multirun.yaml
└── param1=10
    └── param2=10
        ├── objective_data.csv
        ├── optimization=reinforcement_learning
        │   └── num_trials=100
        │        └── learning_rate=1e-4
        │            └── seed=42
        │                 └── output.csv
        │ 
        └── optimization=replicator_dynamic
            └── num_trials=1
                 └── rd_hparam=5
                      └── seed=42
                          └── output.csv
```

I've mainly been looking into ways of combining `override_dirname` as explained in the hydra tutorial [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/configure_hydra/workdir/#configuration-for-run) together with string interpolation. But this only gets me so far -- what I really need is to be able to specify a *condition* for what the job-specific subdirectory is, based on the values I'm sweeping in multisweep.

The **main reason** I'm worried that what I want to do is **not possible** is that it appears that I want to change fields of `hydra.run` and `hydra.sweep`, which are populated at runtime, according to the [docs](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/configure_hydra/intro/#hydraruntime). I know that I can access them, but can I change their fields? If I could edit these fields somehow, then I would probably just implement all of my folder logic in code, instead of trying to do sophisticated string interpolation.

Less relevant, things that I've looked into:

I initially had some suspicion that what I should use is some kind of [custom resolver](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_resolvers.html) from OmegaConf, because then perhaps I could pass the config object or fields of it to a custom-built resolver function that has precisely the logic I want. But whether and how to do this is not clear to me.

Finally, I've been avoiding trying to edit paths from `hydra.utils.get_original_cwd` by hand, because hydra seems to have a lot of support for automatic subdirectory creation.